# How do I get the Truecrypt CLI installed?

Tags: osx, gpg, truecrypt

I have a unix machine with truecrypt 7.1a installed. I'm trying to mount a volume to test with the command line but I don't have the truecrypt command installed evidently. Did the command line functionality come with the install before the software went crazy or am I doing something crazy? Or is there a place to download the the necessary files to put it on my machine?

Comment: [tcplay](https://github.com/bwalex/tc-play) is a free (BSD licensed) TC command line implementation...

Comment: It seems that works well with some Linux distros but not Mac (Unix). What about a cli for a Mac?

Comment: No idea: add the [tag:osx] tag to see if that attracts knowledgeable comment...

Comment: thanks. I also found [DMcrypt](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/DMCrypt) for other linux machines while searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found it out myself by scouring the web. You just use the path to the truecrypt executable in the app bundle:

```
/Applications/TrueCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/TrueCrypt -h
```

The above command will get you the help option to see what other options there are for TrueCrypt. Also, here is one of the sources I found for the code: [mount-dev-volumes.sh](https://gist.github.com/codebrane/4032174)